# How can I clean a buildozer custom recipe build?

Tags: buildozer, python-for-android

I have a `buildozer` project that has custom `python-for-android` recipes in the directory `p4a/recipes/`.

One of my recipes needs some debugging, and I don't want to rebuild python and all these other programs every time I want to rebuild it.

I've tried `buildozer android p4a -- clean_recipe_build recipe-name` but it doesn't find it (running `recipes` shows only the vanilla recipes, not my custom ones).

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's an undocumented argument `--local-recipes` that solves it. But since we're running under `buildozer` that changes the working dir before running p4a, we have to supply an absolute path:

```
buildozer android p4a -- clean_recipe_build recipe-name --local-recipes ~/p4a/recipes/
```

And now it works (but note that the docs warn some misbehaviours by recipes would require a full clean, so if things keep being weird, just `p4a -- clean`). Also, note the `--`, it's important, and once again - the path must be absolute and not relative.